# SSRS cascading parameters with 'Allow Null' - enable only when selected param value is not null

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am implementing SSRS cascading parameters:
Country
State
City

Each of the above params gets the 'available values' from respective datasets. There is no default value set.

Each dataset has got the respective values and an additional record with label 'All Values' and value NULL. I am cascading the country value into state; and country and state cascade into City to populate appropriate values for City. This is working fine.

The params are of type text and are configured to not allow nulls, not allow blank and not allow multiple values. In the report preview I can see that it asks me to  for the country param, and the other 2 params are disabled. When I click on view report, it forces me to select the value for Country following which it populates the State and only when I select state it populates City and then once I select City it allows me to run the report.

However, when all the parameters have their settings changed to 'Allow Nulls', the dropdowns are pre-populated with the foll. value - 'All values'. This is because NULL = 'All values'. This Country value get auto passed into State as null and hence State dropdown shows as 'All values' and similarly, the city dropdown.

Question: I need the Country dropdown to initially show 'All values' (null). However, I would like to disable the State and City dropdowns unless the Country value is changed to something other than 'All values' (null). And while the State and City dropdowns are disabled, I would like that the State and City param value is NULL and should allow me to run the report (because the child param will anyways has 'All values' (null) as preselected and the only available option). So effectively I need to be able to run the report along with the enable/disable effect that cascading gives. Is this possible in SSRS?

Comment: Why not set all the default values to null. Since State and City rely on Country, their respective queries will not change until Country has a value. If set up correctly, only the country will be selectable by default. Selecting  All Countries is essentially selecting All States within that Country and All Cities within all states, right?

Comment: I need to be able to run the report along with the enable/disable effect that cascading usually gives

Comment: If you pass in null for all three values, are you getting an exception or prompt?

Comment: No. Its fine. But my questions is - if the first parameter is set to 'All values' (null), then why do I have to allow user to choose the other parameters? Since param1 is null, the other parameter dropdown will have only one value anyways - that is 'All values'. Am I making sense?

Comment: That is where I am confused. By setting the allow nulls on city and state, users should not be required to set those values. Perhaps you are missing a stored procedure or sql that runs even with country is null, forcing only one record back for depended dropdowns, the All Values record(null), even when the parent is null. GetCities(@StateID INT<--Can be null) <--If StateID is null return NULL | "All Values"

Comment: Sorry in my comment when I said " then why do I have to allow user to choose the other parameters?" - I mean that since the child parameter is pre-populated/selected value is 'All values' and 'All values' is the only option since the parent param passes in null to the child param, why do we need to even show the child dropdown as enabled. Is it making sense now please?

Comment: I think when a drop down is disabled in the klunky UI it only indicates that the dependent/parent value has not yet been set. I don't think that is something you have control over.